# Why is our sun yellow in color?

Tags: optics, astrophysics, sun

We know that sunlight or light incident from sun on earth is white in color or have all frequencies of light in visible electromagnetic spectrum.

However I have read that sun is a yellow medium star, and satellite pictures indeed show it is $yellowish-orange$ in color.

Why is this case that sun is deemed as a yellow star but have white light incident from it?
Is it due to our atmosphere or something else?

Comment: The sun is a black body radiator at $T\approx 5800K$.

Comment: Surface Temp = 5800K

Comment: So is temperature is role player in determining color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? See [How can sunlight be white , but pictures of the sun be orange?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74865/268406)